# как установить конкретную версию rspec для проэкта

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

Как можно строго указать версию rspec в гемфайле
При том, если прописываю вручную

```
gem "rspec", '3.5.1'
```

то после комманды `bundle install` ругается на

> Could not find gem 'rspec (= 3.5.1) in any of the gem sources listed
>   in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

хоть и `rpec -v` показывает `3.5.1`

Comment: А директива `source` в гемфайле есть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Немного непонятно, с гемами. В цитате из гемфайла используется какой-то `rpec`, хотя бандлер ругается на `rspec`. Рискну предположить, что вопрос именно про `rspec`.
2. Ни [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec) ни [офф. репозиторий `rspec`'a](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) не знают про версию `3.5.1`.
   Если им верить, то последняя версия это `3.5.0`.
   `3.5.1` есть только для [rspec-core](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core)

Comment: да, пардон за опечатку с `rspec`. С 3.5.0 действительно получилось. Но интересно почему баш показывает версию рспека 3.5.1

Comment: @ddeadlink потому что `rspec` это мета-гем, т. е. "гем из гемов", а зависимости от версий [указаны "пессимистом `~>`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec/blob/master/rspec.gemspec#L35), т. е. `'>= 3.5.0', '<3.6.0'`". А исполняемый файл находится в `rspec-core`, поэтому и версия показывается из него. Такие дела.